# Adding percentages with two letters in strings with JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, percentage, addition

I'm using the following table with percentages that show whether or not the letter after a certain one will be a vowel or a consonant.

```
a: C= 90%, V=  7% 
b: C= 32%, V= 65% 
c: C= 40%, V= 59% 
d: C= 17%, V= 77% 
e: C= 79%, V= 14% 
f: C= 31%, V= 68% 
g: C= 35%, V= 57% 
h: C=  8%, V= 85% 
i: C= 82%, V= 16% 
j: C=  0%, V= 98% 
k: C= 18%, V= 71% 
l: C= 26%, V= 74% 
m: C= 14%, V= 83% 
n: C= 49%, V= 47% 
o: C= 79%, V= 15% 
p: C= 43%, V= 57% 
q: C=  0%, V=100% 
r: C= 31%, V= 64% 
s: C= 61%, V= 36% 
t: C= 28%, V= 67% 
u: C= 90%, V=  9% 
v: C=  1%, V= 99% 
w: C= 22%, V= 71% 
x: C= 15%, V= 72% 
y: C= 58%, V= 24% 
z: C=  7%, V= 91%
```

For example, there is a **58%** chance that the letter after **y** will be a consonant.

I have an array with the following values:

```
var arr = ["Cookie", "Bird", "Flower"];
```

I need for JavaScript to go through each element and take each work and add up **percentages** if they are not in the majority. For example:

---

Cookie:

**CO** <- Because a C going to an O is within the majority, **59%**, nothing will be added.

**OO** <- Because an O going to an O (Vowel to vowel) is not in the majority (only 15% of cases) **79%** will be added

**OK** <- Because its an O going to a K (vowel to consonant), nothing will be added.

**KI** <- Because its a K going to a I (consonant to vowel), nothing will be added.

**IE**  <- Because an I going to an E (Vowel to vowel) is not in the majority (only 16% of cases) **82%** will be added

---

In the end, it should be 79% + 82% = **161**. I have the following code that works on a **string**, not an **array**.

```
var str = 'Cookie';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(str[i] + str[i + 1]);
}
```

This gives the following output in the console:

```
CO 
OO
OK
KI
IE
```

So I have the basic functionality with the string down, but how would I get it to work with an array and add the percentages?

Comment: What is the Javascript data format of your table of percentages?  You haven't shown that data in actual Javascript format so we can only provide actual working code if you show us the exact Javascript format of the data.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to get a very clean prev, current variables so we can compare the transition very easily. You only need to check if the current character is actually a vowel or not. Then you check the probability for the transition, if it's higher than 50, you'll use the opposite of the transition and add it to an accumulator. And that's it.

One thing though, I didn't cover iteration over an array of strings. Mainly because I don't have the whole statistics in an object, so I can only provide one working string.

```js
var options = {
  c: {
    C: 40,
    V: 59
  },
  o: {
    C: 79,
    V: 15
  },
  k: {
    C: 18,
    V: 71
  },
  i: {
    C: 82,
    V: 16
  },
  e: {
    C: 79,
    V: 14
  }
}

var vowels = {
  a : true,
  e : true,
  i : true,
  o : true,
  u : true
  }

function isVowel(chr){
  if(vowels[chr] !== undefined){
    return true;
    } else {
      return false;
      }
  }

var results = document.getElementById('results');
var string = 'Cookie';
var acc = 0;
Array.prototype.reduce.call(string, function(prev, current) {
  if (prev != '') {
    var key = isVowel(current) ? 'V' : 'C';
    var keyOpp = key == 'V' ? 'C' : 'V';
    var letter = options[prev.toLowerCase()];
    var transition = letter[key];
    results.innerHTML += (prev + current + '\n').toUpperCase();
    var opp = letter[keyOpp];
    if(transition < 50){
       acc += opp;
      }
  }
  return current;
}, '');

results.innerHTML += 'Sum : ' + acc;
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a function to an array, you can use the ES5 `Array.prototype.forEach` like so:

```
arr.forEach(function () {
    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
      console.log(str[i] + str[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

This is all well and good when just printing to console, but since you seem to want to be mapping from your words to scores, you should check out [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

As for checking whether or not you've hit a consonant or a vowel, you should declare `var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']` and use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check whether you have a vowel. You can then use boolean operators to find out whether vowels or consonants are in majority and create your score function from there.

**Update**: `x in object` is better than `Array.prototype.indexOf`

You should store vowels as keys in a JavaScript object:

```
vowels = {'a': true, 'e': true, 'i': true, 'o': true, 'u': true}
```

Then `'a' in vowels` returns `true` and `'b' in vowels` returns `false`. This is much faster than calling `indexOf` on an array.

Note that the value you assign doesn't really matter here, but it does allow for evaluating `vowels['a']` instead of `'a' in vowels`, though I believe this will be a more expensive operation, but perhaps you'll want to conditionally discount `e` for whatever reason: you can then set `vowels['e'] = false`.

Comment: No, vowels should go in an object, not an array, and then testing for them is comparable for testing when something exists in a hash.  Array.prototype.indexOf is an expensive operation, it entails looping over the array every time.

Comment: It may not matter so much for an array so small, but in general it is to be preferred

Comment: I'll steal this suggestion :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to iterate an array in JavaScript, very similar to how you iterated the string.

```
var array = ['Cookie','Bird','Flower'];
for (var j = 0, j = array.length; j++) {
  var str = array[j];
  //...
}
```

Within this loop, you can iterate through the string and apply your logic

```
var array = ['Cookie','Bird','Flower'];
for (var j = 0, j = array.length; j++) {
  var str = array[j];

  for (var i = 0, i < str.length; i++) {
     // your logic  
  }
}
```